# Both navigation are coming out, how to hide the second navigation when first navigation is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

I'm having issues with two navigation bars in mobile. When I click on the first navigation bar icon, both navigation is coming out. I'm trying the CSS visibility: none code upon clicking the icon but I'm not getting the right outcome. Can you please help me?

I have attached images below for your reference.

This is the two navigation bars. One in black, one in white.

[image]

This is the where I'm getting the issue. As you can see both are coming out.
[image]

This is what happens when we click on navigation bar 2. This is correct.
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Visibility option from here:

```
.td-js-loaded .td-menu-background, .td-js-loaded #td-mobile-nav {
    /* visibility: visible;    ----- remove this */
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.79, 0.14, 0.15, 0.86);
    -moz-transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.79, 0.14, 0.15, 0.86);
    -o-transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.79, 0.14, 0.15, 0.86);
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.79, 0.14, 0.15, 0.86);
}
```

Add Visibility to :

```
.td-menu-mob-open-menu #td-mobile-nav {
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;    /* it's added here */
}
```

And in:

```
.td-menu-mob-open-menu .td-menu-background {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;    /* it's added here */
}
```

It will solved your current issue.

but you have to do two more think, so that if user open 2nd nav and scroll he can see only navigation menu until, he/she don't close this.

```
.td-menu-background {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    position: absolute;   /* before it was position: fixed; */
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 113%;
    z-index: 9999;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
```

And for showing cross button on white background, you should change the color of it:

```
.td-mobile-close .td-icon-close-mobile {
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #bdbdbd;  /* before it was "color: #fff;" if you don't like "color: #bdbdbd;" you can change it with your desire color  */ 
    top: 4px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Zahidul-Islam-Ruhel , thank you so much! Your solution worked in my website. My minor problem is the close button for the first navigation, it's not showing as expected but overall, you have resolved this issue. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you let me check by providing your website link. 

_Note: Please let me know where you want to show your close button._